How do I fix this React failure to compile error when using the Groq API?
I am trying to use the Groq AI in my app to be able to add a feature where users can send a message to the AI and get back a response. But I am running into the following error
./node_modules/groq-sdk/index.js 78:32
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (78:32)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|     super({
|       baseURL: options.baseURL,
>       timeout: options.timeout ?? 60000 /* 1 minute */,
|       httpAgent: options.httpAgent,
|       maxRetries: options.maxRetries,

I am following their API docs here https://console.groq.com/docs/quickstart and seem to have done everything listed in my app. Does anyone know what may be happening?
This is my React component
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Groq from "groq-sdk";

function AI() {
  const groq = new Groq({
    apiKey: "<MY API KEY HERE>",
  });

  async function main() {
    const chatCompletion = await getGroqChatCompletion();
    // Print the completion returned by the LLM.
    console.log(chatCompletion.choices[0]?.message?.content || "");
  }

  async function getGroqChatCompletion() {
    return groq.chat.completions.create({
      messages: [
        {
          role: "user",
          content: "Explain the importance of fast language models",
        },
      ],
      model: "llama3-8b-8192",
    });
  }

  main();

  return (
    <section className="my-5">
      <div className="my-2">
        <h1>Coming Soon!</h1>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

export default AI;



This is a build problem. Your project's Babel configuration does not have an appropriate configuration to handle the nullish coalescing operator (??) the library is using. Please share your babel configuration/build tooling config.

where can i find my babel configuration?

i don't think i have any, i am on a simple create-react-app @adsy
